# SQL SERVER: CURSOR FETCH causes error while identical row works fine

Tags: sql-server, cursor, fetch

**the context**

I am working on a SQL server database for my e-mobility research. In this database we store charge sessions of electric cars in the Netherlands. Part of the ETL is to transform the recorded charge sessions into a new table that stores the (arrival) time between the charge sessions.

**the problem**

I use a cursor `crChargeSessions` in which I FETCH columns into variables. I do this 3 times. First a fetch in variables called @old[etc] then @new[etc] and at last again in @new[etc]. 
t
SQL server displays an error at this last FETCH row, while this row is a full copy of the other row. How is it possible that a row that works in the first place doesnt work a few rows later??

note: I deleted the @variable declarations for readability improvement
    USE [CHIEF_Production]
    DECLARE crChargeStation CURSOR SCROLL FOR 
        SELECT [PostalCode],[Nr] 
        FROM [dbo].TBL_ChargeSessions 
        GROUP BY [PostalCode],[Nr]

```
 OPEN crChargeStation

 FETCH NEXT FROM crChargeStation
 INTO @strPostalCode ,@strNumber

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

    DECLARE crChargeSessions CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT [ChargeSession_ID]
        ,[PostalCode]
        ,[Nr]     
        ,[RFID]
        ,[StartConnectionDate]
        ,[StartConnectionTime]
        ,[EndConnectionDate]
        ,[EndConnectionTime]
        ,[kWh]
    FROM [dbo].TBL_ChargeSessions 
    WHERE [PostalCode] = @strPostalCode AND [Nr] = @strNumber AND ([LambdaSyncRFID] = 0)
    ORDER BY  [EndConnectionDate] ASC ,  [StartConnectionTime] ASC

    OPEN crChargeSessions
```

FIRST TIME I FETCH

```
FETCH NEXT FROM crChargeSessions    INTO @LastChargeSession_ID, @strPostalCode, @strNumber ,@strLastRFID ,@dtlastStartConnectionDate ,@dtLastStartConnectionTime, @dtlastEndConnectionDate, @dtLastEndConnectionTime, @LastkWh
```

SECOND TIME I FETCH

```
FETCH NEXT FROM crChargeSessions    INTO @NewChargeSession_ID,  @strPostalCode, @strNumber ,@strNewRFID  ,@dtNewStartConnectionDate ,@dtNewStartConnectionTime, @dtNewEndConnectionDate, @dtNewEndConnectionTime, @NewkWh

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN   


        SET @dcDeltaBBConnection = CAST ((@dtNewStartConnectionDate + @dtNewStartConnectionTime) - (@dtlastStartConnectionDate + @dtLastStartConnectionTime) as decimal(18,6))
        SET @dcDeltaEBConnection = CAST ((@dtNewStartConnectionDate + @dtNewStartConnectionTime) - (@dtlastEndConnectionDate + @dtLastEndConnectionTime) as decimal(18,6))

            PRINT @strChargeStation

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_Lambda_ChargeStation]
           ([Nr]
           ,[PostalCode]
           ,[LastRFID]
           ,[NewRFID]
           ,[LastStartConnectionDate]
           ,[LastStartConnectionTime]
           ,[NewStartConnectionDate]
           ,[NewStartConnectionTime]
           ,[deltaBeginBegin]
           ,[deltaEndBegin]
           ,[LastkWh]
           ,[NewkWh])
       VALUES
            (@strNumber
            ,@strPostalCode
            ,@strLastRFID
            ,@strNewRFID
            ,FORMAT(@dtlastStartConnectionDate ,'MM-dd-yyyy')
            ,FORMAT(@dtLastStartConnectionTime  ,'hh:mm:ss' )
            ,FORMAT(@dtNewStartConnectionDate ,'MM-dd-yyyy')
            ,FORMAT(@dtNewStartConnectionTime,'hh:mm:ss')
            ,@dcDeltaBBConnection 
            ,@dcDeltaEBConnection
            ,@LastkWh
            ,@NewkWh)

        -- UPDATE boolean 
            UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_ChargeSessions] SET [LambdaSyncStation] = 1 WHERE [dbo].[TBL_ChargeSessions].[ChargeSession_ID] = @lastChargeSession_ID


            SET @strLastRFID = @strNewRFID
            SET @dcDeltaBBConnection = 0
            SET @dcDeltaEBConnection = 0
            SET @lastChargeSession_ID =  @NewChargeSession_ID
            SET @dtlastStartConnectionDate =  @dtNewStartConnectionDate
            SET @dtLastStartConnectionTime =  @dtNewStartConnectionTime
            SET @dtlastEndConnectionDate =  @dtNewEndConnectionDate
            SET @dtLastEndConnectionTime =  @dtNewEndConnectionTime
            SET @LastkWh =  @NewKWh
```

THIRD TIME I FETCH
        FETCH NEXT FROM crChargeSessions    INTO @NewChargeSession_ID,  @strPostalCode, @strNumber ,@strNewRFID  ,@dtNewStartConnectionDate ,@dtNewStartConnectionTime, @dtNewEndConnectionDate, @dtNewEndConnectionTime, @NewkWh

```
    END

    CLOSE crChargeSessions
    DEALLOCATE crChargeSessions 


    FETCH NEXT FROM crChargeStation
    INTO @strChargeStation 
END


CLOSE crChargeStation
DEALLOCATE crChargeStation
```

END

Comment: What do you mean with *this row is a full copy of the other row*?, are you saying that your table has 3 identical rows?

Comment: If you post more details someone may be able to demonstrate a version that does not require cursors.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. with full copy I meant that it this 3rd row is an exact copy of the 2nd row.

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you for this proposal, but i'd rather keep my code with CURSORS at this moment, since I have another version of this stored procedure for another table that works perfect...

Comment: And what is the error then?, can you post more details?. You are just saying: "then there's some code and a row that throws an error", not much that we can do with that information

Comment: This is the error:
    Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Procedure stpLambdaSyncChargeStation, Line 132
Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

Comment: @JRHelmus And are you absolutely sure that this is the **exact** code that you are using in your `FETCH`s?

Comment: Yes, well... I simply copy pasted the row...I mean It then should/ougt/must be the same. Unless MS SQL Server has it's own will.

Comment: @JRHelmus Well, your question changed somehow significantly, adding this part of the code: `FETCH NEXT FROM crChargeStation INTO @strChargeStation`. That cursor is supposed to receive fetch 2 columns, not one, hence your error. In an unrelated note, why are you performing 2 fetches from the `crChargeSessions` cursor consecutively?, do you understand what that does?

Comment: Hi YES , thank you so much that was it! So stupid. Great to have someone else looking at your code.